# Firestore rules are not working in emulator for cloud functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am working with the demo example

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
var message = "message";

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access Firestore.
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.addMessage = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const original = req.query.text;
  const writeResult = await admin.firestore().collection(message).add({original: original});
  res.json({result: `Message with ID: ${writeResult.id} added.`});
});

exports.makeUppercase = functions.firestore.document('/' + message + '/{documentId}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {
      const original = snap.data().original;
      functions.logger.log('Uppercasing', context.params.documentId, original);
      
      const uppercase = original.toUpperCase();
      return snap.ref.set({uppercase}, {merge: true});
    });
```

And this is my rule -

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

What I expected is that the `makeUppercase` would not execute if the allow read and write is set to false. I know that `addMessage` would work because of admin privileges but why `makeUppercase` is executing in emulator.

Answer (score 4):

The security rules of your Firestore database only apply to data access coming from client-side SDKs, such as those for Android, iOS and from the browser-based web.

Cloud Functions access Firestore using the Admin SDK, which means they have administrative privileges and bypass the security rules. This behavior (which applies in the emulators as well as in production) can not be altered.

Comment: Thanks! Frank but what if I want to have validations rules on triggers?

Comment: There is no way to alter this behavior: Firestore's security rules are not evaluated for access through the Admin SDK.